# IndexOutOfRangeException When serializing an Entity Object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, serialization

I'm using WCF with Entity Framework. I have a Web Service that returns an object that points to an array of a certain entity object. When the Silverlight Client called the method, i get a 'NotFound' exception.

I explored the WCF log and Event Log and discovered the error was a IndexOutOfRangeException ocurring when serializing the object. There was a big stack trace, wich when i analysed the following catches my eye. Before that, a snippet of my model (I translated the names to ease understanding):

```
Entity BaseItem:
   (Some properties)
   DetailItem[] Details;

Entity DetailItem:
   (Some properties)
   RelatedItem ExtraInfo;

Entity RelatedItem:
   (Some properties)
```

Then i had this callstack:

```
   (...)
   in WriteArrayOfDetailItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   in WriteBaseItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   in WriteDetailItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   in WriteArrayOfDetailItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   in WriteRelatedItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   in WriteDetailItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   ib WriteArrayOfDetailItemToXml(...)
   (...)
   em WriteBaseItemToXml(...)
   em System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.WriteXmlValue(...)
```

It seems to me serializer entered a recursion loop trying to write all properties, including reciprocal properties (I don't know if thats the name, i mean the properties generated by the framework in both sides of a relation).

Does anyone have a clue of what could be happening and whats causing this error?

Comment: Take care on serialization and Lazy load enabled because often you risk to serialize the whole database... There are several articles about this. For sure, if you have a public property the serializer will read it and the framework will retrieve it from DB (if you have Lazy load enabled).

Comment: How do i Know if Lazy Loading is enabled?

Comment: It's a property of the context, Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled. I found this article on MSDN that also speak about serialization https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#lazySerialization . It just says what I wrote before...